Ubuntu 24.04 Thinkpad T14 Gen 5 Intel suspend on lid close
I got a Gen 5 Intel and everything was working perfectly till a few days ago, but now it doesn't suspend when I close the lid. I'm on Ubuntu 24.04, kernel 6.8.0-50-generic, but I cannot track down which update broke it. Is anyone else experiencing such behaviour?

I updated to kernel 6.11.0-1009-oem (linux-oem-24.04b package) and now it works again.
Note: I was seeing some i915 errors in dmesg with kernel 6.8. Don't know if this was related to the issue, just mentioning it.
